# Google cloud print driver for Windows 10, error 0x80070705

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printing, printer, google-cloud-print

I'm trying to install the [google cloud print driver for Windows](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/cloudprintdriver) (version 58.0.3020.0) to be able to print normal word documents to my google cloud-registered printers. When I run the installer I get the following error message:

[image: Error message]

Translated to English, it says:

```
Error 0x80070705 occurred within the installer with the error message "Unknown printer driver"
```

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud Printer\58.0.3020.0\debug.log` contains:

```
[0619/143106.829:WARNING:setup.cc(245)] Unable to open printer
[0619/143110.688:WARNING:setup.cc(165)] Uploading the printer driver package to the driver cache silently failed. Will retry with user UI. HRESULT=0x800f0242
[0619/143131.064:ERROR:setup.cc(185)] Installing the printer driver failed.
[0619/143131.064:ERROR:setup.cc(275)] Unable to install driver.
[0619/143131.064:ERROR:install_utils.cc(100)] The printer driver is unknown.

[0619/143131.064:INFO:setup.cc(426)] The printer driver is unknown.
 HRESULT=0x80070705
[0621/191645.908:WARNING:setup.cc(245)] Unable to open printer
[0621/191647.104:ERROR:setup.cc(185)] Installing the printer driver failed.
[0621/191647.104:ERROR:setup.cc(275)] Unable to install driver.
[0621/191647.104:ERROR:install_utils.cc(100)] The printer driver is unknown.
```

Where the last 6 lines repeat a couple of times (with different numbers at the start), probably because I have tried to install the driver multiple times already.

I have tried both the most recent "normal" chrome version 59.0.3071, and the current canary version 61.0.3141.0 for installing the driver. I'm running Windows 10.0.14393 on a HP ProBook 4730s.

Does somebody know what the problem is?

Comment: Have you installed the required [XPS Essentials Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11816)?

Comment: @DavidPostill Wow I can't image I didn't read that. There are only versions for Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista and Windows XP though, which one should I use?

Comment: I've no idea... :)

Comment: Turns out that isn't the issue, XPS is included in Windows starting from W7.

Answer (score 2):

USE the beta version
https://tools.google.com/dlpage/cloudprintservice
it will solve the issue

Comment: Consider adding some quoted reference to this answer supporting what you state in case the link ever dies so the answer content is still available that is currently only available via that link per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I found no solution that fixed the issue for me on Windows Server 2016 x64.
It seems like it fails with the commonly mentioned 0x80070057 error:

```
HRESULT=0x80070057
[0429/234050.669:ERROR:install_utils.cc(100)] Wrong parameter.
[0429/234050.669:INFO:setup.cc(426)] Wrong parameter.
HRESULT=0x80070057
```

For me the fix was to copy gcp_portmon64.dll to Windows\System32 (My system is x64, I assume x86 needs the gcp_portmon.dll instead.
Then I made a copy of C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud Printer\58.0.3020.0
(These files install when the installer fails)
Modified the gcp_driver.inf file adding just at the bottom of the file:
(I assume you remove the '64', if you are on x86.

```
[PortMonitors]
"Google Port Monitor" = GooglePortMon

[GooglePortMon]
CopyFiles = @gcp_portmon64.dll
PortMonitorDll = gcp_portmon64.dll
```

Then running the virtual_driver_setup.exe file, and it should install the port monitor, else try it manually from devices and printers => server properties.
If it installs, try run the original installer again, as modifying the file breaks digital signing, so the printer wont install.
I hope this helps anybody a bit further.